# Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels. Using confusionMatrix (caret)

Tags: r, r-caret, confusion-matrix

I am getting an error when using the `confusionMatrix()` function from the `caret` package. To reproduce the example, I use the `Sonar` dataset from the `mlbench` package.

```
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)

rows <- sample(nrow(Sonar))
Sonar <- Sonar[rows, ]


split <- round(nrow(Sonar) * 0.6)
adiestramiento <- Sonar[1:split, ]
experimental <- Sonar[(split + 1):nrow(Sonar), ]

model <- glm(Class ~ ., family = binomial(link = "logit"), adiestramiento)
p <- predict(model, experimental, type = "response")
p_class <- ifelse(p > 0.5, "M", "R")

library(caret)
confusionMatrix(p_class, experimental[["Class"]])
```

The error I am getting when running `confusionMatrix()` is

> Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels`

I checked that both `p_class` and `experimental[["Class"]]` have the same number of objetcs (83).

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `data` or, in this case, `p_class` has to be a factor. So, instead we should use

```
confusionMatrix(factor(p_class), experimental[["Class"]])
# Confusion Matrix and Statistics
# 
#           Reference
# Prediction  M  R
#          M 17 20
#          R 33 13
# ...
```